# Can the constraint name be reused else were in the SQL query?

Tags: sql-server, constraints, check-constraints

[image]

When creating a constraint can you use the name, in this case `checkChar`, for other values. What does having the name actually do anyway? Can it be reused elsewhere?

Also, why does it give a "sort of error" if the values are the same in the column and then it will not let you change them (see below).

Code:

```
 CREATE TABLE EEE
 (
 FirstName  varchar (50)
 CONSTRAINT checkChar CHECK ([FirstName] LIKE '%[A-Za-z]%')
 )
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two questions there.

**Reusing check-constraints across tables**

This is not possible (AFAIK). Don't know the exact reason why, but it is a good thing: when you decide later to modify a check constraint you do that only on the tables that need it. If it were a global constraint then you'd be tempted to modify it without thinking on the implications for all/other tables.

Usually you prefix the constraints with the table name: `EEE_checkChar` - this way you can avoid tje uniqueness rule.

**Sort of error when editing the records with SSMS**

That error is not caused by the constraint. It is because you have two identical rows in that table and it is not possible to uniquely identify either of them. SQL Server is not able to detect which row is which when you want to do something with them.

You can hover over the red badge and the message will be something like: `The row value updated or deleted does not make the row unique or it alters multiple rows`.

What you can do:

1. Add another column, for example `INT`, `IDENTITY(1, 1)`
2. Add another column with unique values.

Typically you add a surrogate primary key to your tables when you are not sure the values are unique. Or, add a uniqueness constraint/index.

Comment: I think every table that I have ever made has a primary key even if it is generated by the system. This was just a test and really I did not put a primary key on. It is interesting at the problems that it will cause when you do not put one on and always assume one is there.